Where does System Preferences read the device's MAC address?
If you go into MacOS System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Hardware:
You will see the device's mac address. Great!
Now, how is system preferences seeing that address? It the mac address is changed (spoofing...etc), this mac address in system preferences does not change (although under ifconfig it is very much changed via spoofing)
I want to change that specific mac address under system preferences. Any input is appreciated.

The OS driver is probably reading the MAC address from the PHY hardware, as that would fetch the value actually in use. Then the question becomes, what was written to the PHY? That answer has various possibilities. For a commercial Ethernet product, the (registered) MAC address is typically stored in an NVRAM (such as a serial EEPROM), and then retrieved and written to the PHY during initialization. See https://www.digikey.com/en/ptm/m/microchip-technology/mac-address-eeproms

@sawdust You're right that it's being read from hardware, but the MAC address is being read from the MAC hardware because as the name implies, it has to do with the MAC function. The PHY is a layer below and is oblivious to MAC concerns such as MAC addresses. This distinction hardly matters nowadays as they're always integrated, but back when they were separate, I assure you the MAC read its address from its own ROM. It never had to ask the PHY to send it across the MII.

A followup question then; can I interface with eeprom from the OS? i.e. can I have my software read the address directly; instead of asking the OS (via ifconfig). btw, novice here; but learning a lot so thanks for the inputs!
